# How increment operator behaves in Java in the complicated statements

Tags: java

```
int x = 3; 
System.out.println(x++ + ++x + x++); // 13
```

Why is the result 13?

My logic:

1. `++x` in the center gives 4
2. `4 + 4 + 4 = 12` so the result must be 12.

Comment: Let's never write code like this.  No one should ever use such a construct in production code.

Comment: This is fun to analyse in Java as it's well-defined. Note that in C and C++, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: x++ does post increment. So in the evaluation the value is 13

Comment: System.out.println(3 + 5 + 5); 
you should first learn basics about increment operator before asking such questions...

Comment: You even asked a similiar question beforehand where @Eran answered you how the post- and preincrement are working. What is confusing you that you still think that the first two operations are still `4+4`?

Comment: You asked a very similar question some hours ago, got an answer and still don't understand it? You still think Java evaluates your expression in a random/unreasonable order ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take it step-by-step. First it is important to note that expressions are evaluated from left to right, so there is no undefined behaviour.

```
int x = 3;
int res = x++ + ++x + x++
// res = (x++) + (++x) + (x++) with x = 3
// res =   3   + (++x) + (x++) with x = 4
// res =   3   +   5   + (x++) with x = 5
// res =   3   +   5   +   5   with x = 6
// res = 13
```

The key part here is that:

- `x++` returns the previous `x` value and increments `x` afterwards. JLS [section 15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) about the "Postfix Increment Operator `++`" says:

  > The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.
- `++x` returns the next `x` incremented value. JLS [section 15.15.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) about the "Prefix Increment Operator `++`" says:

  > The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the variable *after* the new value is stored.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! You have explained perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(x++ + ++x + x++); // 13 

                    3     5     5
System.out.println(x++ + ++x + x++); // 13
```

`x++` - **executes then increments**, `so 3`

`++x` - `above 3 incremented to 4`, **++x increments first then executes**, so `4+1=5`

`x++` - **executes first increment later**, `so x=5` is used, `but after this execution x becomes 6`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have explained very well!

Answer (score 2):

`x++` is an expression evaluating to the value *before* the increment. When you see `x++` you can think of it as

```
int result = x;
x = x + 1;
// do something with result.
```

`++x` can be thought of as

```
x = x + 1;
int result = x;
// do something with result.
```

The expression in the question is evaluated from left to right. You can think of it as

```
int x = 3

int result1 = x;  // 3
x = x + 1;

x = x + 1;
int result2 = x;  // 5

int result3 = x;  // 5
x = x + 1;

System.out.println(result1 + result2 + result3);
```

Comment: Thank you! You have tried a lot!